# Unable to import the existing Eclipse project structure to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, import, android-studio

I have a problem with the import of my company's project into Android Studio.

First of all, we have a project which contains desktop clients (Java) and mobile clients (Android). The project structure under Eclipse runs fine.

But since Eclipse and ADT is not longer supported by Google, I thought it is time to switch to Android Studio (I am the first one, who is trying this).

Our project (trunk) has a structure like this:

- 10 Folders which doesn't contain relevant code for the Android Client
- mobile (Android based code)
- projects (Android xmls, manifest and all other non-Java stuff)
- sharedContent (pure Java)

"mobile" contains all the specific source code for the Android client.
The "projects" folder contains a folder "android", which contains all necessary xml-files and the manifest.
The "sharedContent"-folder contains a "sharedME" folder. The code from the "mobiles"-folder uses some code from the "sharedME"-folder.

This three directories are required for the Android client.
The main problem is, that I am not allowed to change the project structure to one, which is more suitable for Android Studio. The reason is, that at first the package declarations wouldn't be correct anymore, and secondly other important code from the project will have problems with the changed structure.

Since we used to import the trunk with SVN, everything worked fine under Eclipse. But I can't integrate the code successfully in Android Studio. I tried many different ways (and tutorials), but none of them worked for me. Note, that the import into the workspace seems to be no problem. But when I am trying to build the project, Android Studio shows me several errors.

I won't show you, what errors I am receiving, because they would be from many different approaches.

I want to start from scratch by asking you, how you would import this project structure with given setting into Android Studio. Maybe I tried the right way, but just made something wrong.

The most favourable solution would be, when the project is connected to the SVN, so that we are able to commit or checkout changes from the SVN directly from Android Studio. But since this doesn't seem to work either, it is ok to commit them manually from the workspace.

I am glad for any suggestions. Just post your ideas, and I will responed with the error output I get or if the solution was successful.

EDIT:
I imported the three most important directories with SVN into Android Studio. Now I have three modules: "android", "mobile", and "sharedContent"
The only error I get is "cannot find symbol, symbol: class R". R is located in android->gen->com->...->project->R. The error is created by the files from the module "mobile", to be exact from mobile->android->com->...->project->A random Class.
Is there a way to point to the R-class, which is located in another module?
Android Studio shows the error at first in the import, like "import com. ... .project.R". I set them as sources, but it didn't work, yet.